# Django view return all objects who's latest state is false

Tags: django, django-views

I have two models: Camera and TimeStamp. Timestamp has a foreign key to Camera, a timestamp, and a current state. I want to return all Cameras whos latest state is false.

```
'faulty': Camera.objects.filter(timestamp__state=False)
```

This returns all camera who have ever had a timestamp that is false. But I just want the cameras who's most recent timestamp_state is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also annotate the latest timestamp to your query and then query against its state. Something like this should do the trick:

```
from django.db.models import F, Max

Camera.objects.annotate(latest_timestamp=Max('timestamp__datetime')).filter(latest_timestamp=F('timestamp__datetime'), timestamp__state=False)
```

Comment: If I made this query like this "context = {
        'cameras': Camera.objects.all(),
        'faulty': Camera.objects.annotate(latest_timestamp=Max('timestamp__timeStamp')).filter(latest_timestamp=F('timestamp__timeStamp'), timestamp__state=False),
    }" How would I then reference the current state?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Q object for this query. Please do some study about Django Q object.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects